# integration with pade approximant

Tags: integration, approximation

given the function

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}exp(-x) $$

can we use Pade approximants to integrate this i mean let bhe te rational approxsiamtions of

$ \sqrt{x}= \frac{A(x)}{B(x)} $ and $ exp(-x)= \frac{C(x)}{D(x)} $

cna i simply evaluate (aproximation) the integral with this ?

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}exp(-x) = \int _{0}^{\infty}\frac{A(x) C(x)}{B(x) D(x)}$$

and the simply do the integration witht eh integrad $ \frac{A(X)C(x)}{B(x)D(x)} $

Comment: You can actually evaluate this integral with elementary tools. Just make the sub $\sqrt{x}=t$ and integrate by parts

Comment: This is, of course, the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) of argument $\dfrac32$, [whose value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function) is $\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2$.